# Is S3 REST for PUT (direct upload) operation chunked?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, put

In S3 REST API, how does the PUT operation i.e. a direct upload not the multipart upload exactly send requests for such large files i.e. Gigabytes through HTTP? Is the direct upload also chunked (like the multipart upload) and has a defined size internally?

When tried doing a PUT (direct upload) operation using S3 REST API, the maximum I could upload was around 5GB which is what even Amazon says their maximum limit for direct upload is. But when tried uploading a file which larger then the limit it throws an exception "Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size" and also has a HTTP response returned where the header tag 'transfer-encoding' is 'chunked'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a randomly-selected error response from S3.

```
< HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
< x-amz-request-id: 207CAFB3CEXAMPLE
< x-amz-id-2: EXAMPLE/DCHbRTTnpavsMQIg/KRRnoEXAMPLEBJQrqR1TuaRy0SHEXAMPLE5otPHRZw4EXAMPLE=
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 19:51:52 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>...
```

The `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header only indicates that the **error response body** S3 is sending back to you will use chunked transfer encoding.

This is unrelated to what is permitted for uploads, and the presence of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in either direction (request or response) of an HTTP transaction is independent of whether it is present or supported in the opposite direction.

The `PUT` object REST API call does not support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` on the **request**.  It requires `Content-Length:` in the request headers, which precludes using chunked transfer encoding.

There is no chunking, blocking, etc., mechanism involved *at the HTTP layer* in standard uploads -- there is no meaningful internal structure "part-size," because there are no parts: it's a continuous TCP stream of un-encoded octets of exactly `Content-Length` length (number of octets/bytes), with retries and network errors handled by TCP, and HTTP unaware of these mechanisms.

If the `Content-Length` header you send exceeds the maximum allowed upload, you get the error about your proposed upload exceeding the maximum allowed size.  If the connection is accidentally or intentionally severed before `Content-Length` number of octets are received by S3, the uploaded data is discarded, because partial objects are never created.